# What is the difference between "귀엽다" and "깜찍하다"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

A lot of people that I met have been calling me like this and I want to know the difference between them.

<sup><del>(I mean, I actually do look quite cute.)</del></sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

귀엽다 is a general term of 'cute'.

깜찍하다 implies being petite, peppy and bubbly, and having lots of 애교.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main difference is that 깜찍하다 has a feeling of  small or even tiny and cute.  귀엽다 is a commoner and broader term for cute, but 깜찍하다 really emphasizes the small size.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀